# Custom fonts with %C in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, fonts

I'm using the musical font "Petrucci" (http://www.music-theory.com/fonts.html) in one iOS app I'm building. I got it working, but there are some problems, when I try to use certain special characters (the font is set correctly on all labels). For Example:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0xf023]
```

displays "#" (the musical note version that comes with Petrucci) where as

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x0023]
```

displays just the Standard font "#". So the difference is "0xf" instead of "0x0" that really makes use of the font.

Now I'm trying to use the symbol "8va" which in standard font would be the sign for the square-root. The code for that sign is U+221a. Using

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x221a]
```

always displays the square-root symbol, not the "8va"-Symbol I'm looking for. And I have no idea how I can somehow make that "0x0" / "0xf" change that works with the above example.

Maybe someone could give me a hint here.

Thanks

J

Comment: Does it work if you use `@"√"`?

Comment: So, is there a table online anywhere for that font?

Comment: @Aaron: No, @"√" does not work, I tried that one.

Comment: @HotLicks, I used the font tool of OS X to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write Unicode characters using `@"\uXXXX"`.

For example, the *sharp* sign would be: `@"\uf023"`.
The *8va* sign would be: `@"\u221a"`.

Comment: It works for the sharp-sign, but @"\u221a" still displays as "√".

Comment: So 221a is not the correct code for that symbol you want. You need to find the correct one.

Comment: OK, I'll try to get a complete list. I was sure about the 221a, as the font tool of OS X displays this value for _8va_.

Comment: After all, the value was wrong. Although the font tool of OS X did display 221a as the value for 8va, another complete list of symbols gave "0195" to use while pressing "ALT" when typing (see http://colorinmypiano.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Petrucci-Character-Map.pdf).

Using 195 as hex value (-> @"\uf0c3") worked.